# IntelliJ warning about filtering Jsoup Elements

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to parse HTML files and I want to get all the `script` elements whose `type` attribute is equal to "dingdong".

Here's the code I've done to try to accomplish that:

```
Stream<String> codeLines = document.getElementsByTag("script")
                .filter(element -> element.attr("type").contentEquals("dingdong"))
                .forEach(Element::data)
                .stream();
```

However, IntelliJ highlights `attr` in red and shows a warning:

[image]

I really can't see what the issue is that IntelliJ is making a fuss about, so any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Note: I'm using IntelliJ with JDK11.0.6.

---

Edit - Here are my imports, as asked:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```

Comment: Can you share your imports?

Comment: Edited my question to include the imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.filter`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#filter-org.jsoup.select.NodeFilter-) method expects a [`NodeFilter`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/NodeFilter.html), not a Predicate as you may have assumed.

You can achieve the same by using [`.select`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#select-java.lang.String-):

```
Stream<String> codeLines = document.getElementsByTag("script")
                .select("[type=dingdong]")
                .stream()
                .map(Element::data);
```

Comment: Thank you for both the answer and correcting `forEach` to `map` :)

Comment: after checking this you can find here: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax more info on how to use selectors inside .select().
You can also chain .select() which was very useful for my use case

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the **stream()**

Elements to has a [filter()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#filter-org.jsoup.select.NodeFilter-) method which may have confused you

It should be:

```
document.getElementsByTag("script").stream()
        .filter(element -> element.attr("type").contentEquals("dingdong"))
        .forEach(Element::data);
```

If a stream is need than use a map instead:

```
Stream<String> stream = document.getElementsByTag("script").stream()
                                .filter(element -> element.attr("type").contentEquals("dingdong"))
                                .map(Element::data);
```